# Perl syntax error near for loop?

Tags: perl

On the code block given below when I run it under linux...

```
my $source = 'BAD-IP-Addresses-LABEL';
my $type_description = 'honeypots-for-examnple';

open(FP, 'your-csv-file.csv')
for my $line (<FP>) {
    my ($hostname, $ip, $something1, $something2) = split(/,/, $line);
    print OUT "$source $type_description $ip #FF0000 0 90  29\n";
}
close(FP);
```

it throws me an error

```
syntax error at ./seculert_rest_qradar.pl line 131, near "$line ("
syntax error at ./seculert_rest_qradar.pl line 135, near "}"
Execution of ./seculert_rest_qradar.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm running the script with chmod 755, for full knowledge of what the script does please go [there.](https://github.com/harvard-itsecurity/qradar-seculert-push)

Kindly suggest.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing semicolon

Comment: @Wooble I didn't know that was an actual category for closing.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: it's a custom reason, since the SO devs stole our "too localized" and when they said single-character typos should be flagged for moderator attention they were lying.

Comment: If you're going to process the file line by line, why read the whole file at once instead of a line at a time? `while (my $line = <FP>) {`

Comment: I'm sorry, how is this off topic?  Can someone explain?

Comment: @ysth [Typo questions are often off topic.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/how-to-flag-a-typo-question) (but not always) This is the subject of some debate.

Comment: here, it seems pretty clear it would be helpful:  when someone gets a syntax error as described, it indicates a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon after your `OPEN` statement:

```
my $source = 'BAD-IP-Addresses-LABEL';
my $type_description = 'honeypots-for-examnple';

open(FP, 'your-csv-file.csv')  # <-- here
for my $line (<FP>) {
    my ($hostname, $ip, $something1, $something2) = split(/,/, $line);
    print OUT "$source $type_description $ip #FF0000 0 90  29\n";
}
close(FP);
```

You don't get the syntax error until partway into the for loop, because this much is perfectly valid perl:

```
open(FP, 'your-csv-file.csv') for my $line
```

Comment: ideally add a mention of why the ( is the syntax error.

Comment: I am actually not entirely sure myself. Care to explain?